# What storage option is best for phonegap in 2019?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap, web-sql

I am new to phonegap. I am coming from android because I want to build a cross plateform app which i want to run on both apple and android devices and i am more skilled in using Web technologies such as JavaScript. now i am half way through and fund webSql is deprecated.I am building a product price app where user will add and store information permanently. so i badly need storage. also some people say i user remove cookies it will delete all storage. what storage option should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check out [MongOGX](https://github.com/globules-io/MongOGX/wiki) if you want to move from SQL to NoSQL with Cordova. MonOGX is a clone of Mongodb

Edit: You can also now use the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) as it is now supported but differs from Mongodb